# Changing layout onOrientationChange

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

Is there a currently supported way to change layouts according to device orientation?
The following code returns this error:

```
 onOrientationChange: function () {
      this.remove();
       this.setLayout( Ext.Viewport.getOrientation() == 'landscape' ?
          { type: 'hbox', pack: 'center', align: 'stretch' } : { type: 'vbox', align: 'stretch', pack: 'center' } );
},
```

"Replacing a layout after one has already been initialized is not currently supported."

Please any one give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the code for the Sencha Meetcha app on GitHub.

What you may have to do, since replacing a layout is unsupported, is use some CSS tricks and when the orientation changes, remove the old cls and apply the new one.

I haven't tried this myself but the demo app seems to do layout changes very well.

Code snippet included

```
orientationCls: ['home-portrait', 'home-landscape'],

doOrientation: function() {
    var me = this,
        orientation = Ext.Viewport.getOrientation(),
        letter = orientation.charAt(0),
        items = this.getItems().getRange(),
        i = 0,
        ln = items.length,
        item, el, top, left;

    me.element.removeCls(me.orientationCls);
    me.element.addCls('home-' + orientation);
    for (; i < ln; i++) {
        item = items[i];
        top = item.initialConfig[letter + 'top'];
        left = item.initialConfig[letter + 'left'];
        el = item.element;
        if (el) {
            el.setBox({
                top: top,
                left: left
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps